# Trouble pushing to Github, cannot spawn sh: No such file or directory

Tags: git, github

I'm having a difficult time pushing to Github..I have a repository that I had cloned, and I have made changes to it that I'd like to push back to github.

While in the repository, I do the following:

```
git add *
```

Which seems to work as I get no response, then when I do:

```
git commit -m "test"
```

I get the response:

```
On branch Will_branch
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

which I expect is where my problem starts.

When I do:

```
git push origin master
git push origin my_branch
```

I get the error:

```
cannot spawn sh: No such file or directory
cannot spawn git: No such file or directory
```

I have gone through so many guides to no avail..thanks for any help.

Comment: Why are you doing `git push origin master/my_branch`? and not `git push origin master:my_branch`?

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't being clear. I meant I tried doing it to master and tried doing it to my branch, on separate occasions.

Comment: I'm hoping its not happening due to a large number of tags in your repo. Check [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/msysgit/6bFAPUQDQLI), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14867232/when-pushing-branches-and-tags-get-error-cannot-spawn-git-no-such-file-or-dir) and [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/msysgit/dR4dtQ2Y0jA).

Comment: Also, the commit response you are getting suggests nothing got committed, do a `git log` to check if the commit actuallyhappened.

Comment: I would but I deleted the repo in the process of trying to find a solution, and now when I try to clone the repo, progress stops at 9%...

Comment: I have posted 2 possible explanations, check if either was the reason in your case.

Comment: Did you figure that out?

Comment: Neither worked, I even emailed GitHub support but they stopped answering my emails. I'm just using the GitHub app on my desktop, which works, for now. If I figure out a solution for my laptop though, I'll be sure to come back and post it.

Comment: Do leave a comment here, if you are able to figure this out on your own, I would love to know the actual reason behind this.

Comment: The error was thrown at me only with the powershell terminal, I opened the gitbash terminal and solved the problem

Answer (score 7):

This might be happening due to a large number of tags in your repo. Check [this google-group entry](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/msysgit/6bFAPUQDQLI), [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14867232/when-pushing-branches-and-tags-get-error-cannot-spawn-git-no-such-file-or-dir) and [another google group entry](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/msysgit/dR4dtQ2Y0jA).

Basically, this is a known issue with `msysgit` and users on google group suggest using the ssh protocol instead as workaround:

1. Uninstall Git (this doesn't uninstall your existing repositories or SSH keys you've generated)
2. Reinstall git at `C:\Git`
3. Open git bash
4. run this command: `export GIT_SSH=/c/Git/bin/ssh.exe`

Also, the commit response you are getting suggests nothing got committed, do a `git log` to check if the commit actually happened.

---

Another reason, as mentioned in this [`msysgit` ticket](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/issues/detail?id=313)  could be the presence of spaces in your Environment variables. Moving the installation of `msysgit` etc to `C:` instead of `C:\Program Files` may solve it.

Answer (score 5):

The offered solution didn't work for me, what I had to do was reinstall Git with one important thing: Make sure to select "Attribute .sh files to git" during the install process and it seems to be all good now.

Comment: Yep.. I had to uninstall Git and reinstall it, making sure that "Attribute .sh files to git" was selected. Then I had to close everything and restart my PC. Fixed! Thanks so much.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue with CLion on Windows 10 when trying to clone from a private repository on gitlab. However, the error vanished without reinstalling, when I added the git binary path (`C:\Program Files\Git\bin` for me) to the PATH variable.

Answer (score 3):

Using Git Bash instead of Windows Command Prompt for `git push` resolved it for me.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue in IntelliJ IDE, what worked for me is to change the access of Git repository from private to public.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to use PowerShell or an external terminal rather than using WebStorm's Terminal and it worked for me.
For me, the issue was while deploying the git code to Github pages. The build was successful but deploying to gh-pages was failing because of the above error.

Answer (score 0):

I did the following steps and it worked:

I deleted the .git folder
I uninstalled the git from c:/program files
I Uninstalled git bash too
Installed the git and git bash now
Initialized git
I checked using the following commands and it worked:

```
git checkout -b vettal // created a new branch 
git push origin vettal // and then made a push
```

Thanks for all the help made through various questions in stackoverflow!

Answer (score 0):

I faced this error when I tried to push my code to GitHub from my VsCode terminal. Then I use gitbash terminal to push my code and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same problem! I was quite stressed after several attempts to solve, and no success!

Just had to

- Install git at C:\Git

In my case, I am facing problems with memory at C, and decided to install all the programs in D. For git, it worked for quite a while! Even if you reinstall in D, it does not work. I had to install in C. and now, it seems to work, hopefully!

Answer (score 0):

For me, I don't pull or push. It shows that error in a vs code terminal (git, cmd, powershell). However, I pull from the git bash tool successfully. ***I think I should just close and reopen my vs code again by git bash tool. Wow, it works.***

```
cd your_sourcecode_folder
code .
```