# Git Push/Pull Local Repository to Local Repository (Windows)

Tags: git

I am working in an office in which multiple people are working on the same project at the same time, therefore we use version control (git). Currently we `push/pull` all of our commits to github.com but I want to set it up so that we `push/pull` them to a particular shared folder.

I have tried using cygwin's sshd and `git daemon` with no luck.

Essentially I would like to cut github out of the picture completely so that I can say command like this:

```
git push S:/repo master

git pull S:/repo master
```

Where `S:/repo` is the shared folder

Any ideas?

Comment: why don't you just clone the project into that shared folder, then just pull whenever you want the latest?

Comment: I am not sure if I understand what you mean. Are you saying clone/pull in the shared folder? But how to I (clone/pull/push) to everyone else's local folder from the shared folder?

Comment: shouldn't they be be pulling to their own local repos as well?  I guess I don't really understand why you need a shared folder.  Can't you just init a repo in a central place to act as a master?

Comment: I want to eliminate github from the equation. So that pushing and pull only happens between the individual users local repository and the center repository contained in the shared folder. Take another look at my question. I just don't want my code to be publicly hosted on github. Instead privately hosted.

Comment: cool, so just init in the shared local folder, and that becomes everyones origin, like mentioned in the answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a repository in folder /mnt/repo by executing

```
git init --bare
```

in that folder.
After that you can add it as a remote to your local repo and push everything you have to it:

```
git remote add origin /mnt/repo
git push origin --all
```

So, if some share is mounted to /mnt/repo, everyone pushing to it will use the same repository.

Comment: So I navigated to my shared drive `S:` and executed the command `git init test --bare`. Then I navigated to `My Desktop` and ran the command `git clone S:/test master` but got `error: cannot spawn sh: No file or directory` and `fatal: unable to fork`. What do you think the issue is?

Comment: I suppose you have to push anything to S:/test before?

Comment: So I run the following commands from `My Desktop`: `mkdir test` then `cd test` then `touch readme.md` then `git init` then `git add -A` then `git commit -m "Initial Commit"` finally `git push S:/test`. Same error and fatal.

Comment: I googled for the error output. It seems it may happen if path contains spaces (or because something else, actually...). May it be the problem here?

Comment: My path does contain spaces but I add quotes around the path. Let me try it in a path with no spaces.

Comment: I changed my paths to be spaceless but still the same error. (I essentially just mounted T: drive to the folder I wanted using `subst` command)

Comment: Chech this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22619355/trouble-pushing-to-github-cannot-spawn-sh-no-such-file-or-directory and the links in the first reply. It could also happen because you cloned empty repository. Or something else. Are you using msysgit?

Comment: Yeah I had to reinstall my msysgit. Thank You!